# What App server to use for json and soap API

Tags: json, authentication, soap, server, frameworks

I am trying to select a app server platform to service JOSN & Soap POST requests from client app on Desktops. The app server runs on linux and use PHP code.

I searched and found PHP framework but that doesn't give you easy to use auth user/password, so you have to do the auth in app code. What is to use for simple request/response app server with secure auth like user/password on first request and then token like normal web servers.

Currently using Drupal 7 REST services module to handle request auth, but SOAP has security issues. Looking for better and light weight framework.

Answer (score 0):

For your API : https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi (it's gonna be implemented in 8.7 anymay)

If you have an external authentication provider (like keycloak, azureAD…) : https://www.drupal.org/project/oauth2_jwt_sso

If you don't : https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_oauth